# Do we need "else" construction if the block "if" has return?

Tags: java

I understand that the following methods do the same, but which variant is better and why?

```
public boolean method() {
      if (condition) {
          return otherMethod();
      } else {
          return true;
      }
}
```

or

```
public boolean method() {
      if (condition) {
          return otherMethod();
      } 
      return true;
}
```

Or maybe is this the better variant?

```
public boolean method() {
     return condition ? otherMethod() : true;
}
```

Comment: I think it's just a matter of preference. I like without `else` for better readability

Comment: For me the second option is easier to read, and use less code. If your code is readable and save some lines i think is the best option

Comment: The second snippet has the advantage of less indentation in the code outside the if statement, which can make the code more readable if you have a lot of code in that section, which may contain other constructs (loop, more if statements, etc...) that require further indentation.

Comment: @khelwood Do you mean `return condition?otherMethod():true;` A pitty none of the 6(!) answers considered this.

Comment: I think what I meant was `return (condition || otherMethod());` or possibly `return (!condition || otherMethod());` depending on the form of the unspecified if-condition in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a very strong opinion about this, which is that it is terrible style to use an `else` block in this situation.

Using `else` will greatly hamper readibility once the logic gets sufficiently complicated.

For example:

```
if (cond1)
   then return
else
    // Do some processing
    if (cond2)
        then return
    else
         // Do some processing
         if (cond3)
             ....
```

So you end up with a deeply nested structure, which is completely unnecessary, because it's equivalent to this:

```
if (cond1)
   then return
// Do some processing
if (cond2)
   then return
// Do some processing
if (cond3)
   ....
```

Comment: Well, yes, but why not just use `else if` to avoid a deeply-nested structure?

Comment: That may not always be possible. For example, maybe I need to do some processing in between those condition checks.

Comment: I agree with Andy. Even though `else if` isn't technically a keyword in Java, most people essentially treat it as if it is. For instance, my IDE is set to always use braces, except when in an else-if.

Comment: I just don't like redundant code, so even if there is not processing in between those condition checks, I would always use `if` and not `else if`

Comment: That's valid, but relatively uncommon -- I wouldn't build a style guide around it, personally.  YMMV :)

Comment: @yshavit I would definitely build a style guide around the principle of avoiding redundant code and unnecessary nesting.

Comment: @wvdz Sure. I meant that _always_ going against the `else` because _sometimes_ you'll want to factor out common code seems like overkill to me. You can either make a more complicated style ("use `else` unless you need to factor out common code, as in ...") or allow some wiggle in the style ("favor `else` unless code is less readable without it"). For me, the first rule of a style guide is that if it leads you astray in a particular instance, you should be allowed to go against it.

Answer (score 1):

Same outcome, different styles, just a matter of taste. 
 I would prefer the **second solution** so the return statement is related to an actual statement (if in this case) and is less redundant. 
 Furthermore the "Else" statement adds complexity of inverting the if condition, which makes it less readable.

Answer (score 1):

I like second option more.

Here's some justification I use for myself:

1) Less nested code and reduced code complexity.

2) Allows early returns:

```
public boolean isValidUser(User user) {
    if (user == null) {
        return false;
    }

    String details = getUserDetails(user);
    if (details == null) {
        return false;
    }

    ...

    return true
}
```

vs

```
public boolean isValidUser(User user) {
    if (user == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        String details = getUserDetails(user);
        if (details == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            ...
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely the same. It is only a different style. Adopt the one that you prefer.

Personally, generally I prefer the second option because if the code is very long is not indented in a block. From my point of view, It is more readable.

Imagine

```
public boolean myFunction() {   
    if (test) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    // Very long code
    return false;
}
```

instead of

```
public boolean myFunction() {   
    if (test) {
        return true;
    } else {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        // Very long code
        return false;
    }
}
```